# Why ping to loopback goes through router or ap

Tags: networking, ping, libpcap, loopback

Well, im making a little packet sniffer as a practice for my degree, and this is the situation... Im flooding my own host with ping packets through 127.0.0.1 and the capture says the packets are entering from the router/ap im connected to. As far as i know loopback address is used to make client/server apps running on the same computer, running even without a connected NIC interface and such... so i thought packets sent to loopback address never leaved the host, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I'll apreciate some light over this scheme.

The packet sniffer works with libpcap and it only works with an active connection, cant know if the scenario would be exactly the same if i watched over lo instead of eth/wl. A brief explanation it's enough to clear my mind. Thanks.

Comment: So you captured on, for example, eth0 (rather than, say, "any") and did `ping 127.0.0.1` (or some program sending ICMP Echo packets to 127.0.0.1), and saw ICMP Echo packets to 127.0.0.1 in that capture?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is why the destination MAC address is the one of the router and not the NIC mac... If you dont have any connected NIC and you make ping to your own host packets would have the same MAC as source/destination true? Why its not the same case when you are connected? why those packets have the router as destination if they are sended to a loopback address?!?!